# How to use multiple instances of the same Blazor component

Tags: components, blazor, lifecycle

I have a tab control and dynamically create tabs with the same component (say, Employee) on each tab.  When the first one is created, the constructor and OnInitialized execute.  But when I create another one (say for another Employee), the constructor and OnInitialized do not execute.  (OnParametersSetAsync runs multiple times for each).

Originally I retrieved the Employee info in OnInitialized.  I understood this to be the preferred practice.  But since it doesn't run for the second Employee, I don't know where to retrieve the second Employee info.  I don't see a predictable behavior for OnParametersSetAsync.

If there was an event that would always run one time in this scenario then that might work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hello and welcome. I think you will have better chances getting help if you provided a sample of your code.

Comment: "If there was an event that would always run one time in this scenario then that might work. Any ideas?" Wrong direction to solve the issue. Please, post complete reproducible code of the issue.

Comment: Here is my example

Comment: I am using BlazorStrap for tabs, but I don't think that matters.  If you look at the first example here: https://github.com/chanan/BlazorStrap/issues/407 You will see a StrategyComp component in the middle of the page.  If there are more than one of these, the constructor and OnInitialized run only for the first one.

Comment: If you post some code, it may be easier to help.

Comment: OnInitialized should run for each instance of your Employee component.  If it's not running, it's not being drawn.  i.e. it's not the currently selected tab.  You should see it run if you select the tab where it's located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to force blazor to re-initialize a component.

One way to achieve that is the usage of @key attribute.

If you set your component like `<EmployeeComponent @key=”@Employee.Id”`, every time you change employee and the parent component rerenders, the blazor diff algorithm will be tricked into creating new EmployeeComponent, instead of re-rendering the old one.

Without your code sample, it is hard to say if it is a right usecase of this technique. There will probably be more elegant solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed.  I had used the @key attribute in another place with BlazorStrap tabs, but I didn't really understand its impact.  (and spent a lot of time trying to figure this out).  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Do not forget to accept the answer.